# Uploading files AJAX Jquery to sails - Couple of questions

Tags: jquery, ajax, sails.js

First the code:

client side code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('upload', dataURLtoBlob(dataUrl));

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Api/File',  //Server script to process data
            type: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'authorization': 'Bearer ' + window.localStorage.aurelia_token
            },
            //Ajax events
            success: (uuid) => {
                alert(uuid);
            },
            error: () => {alert('Error!');},
            // Form data
            data: formData,
            //Options to tell jQuery not to process data or worry about content-type.
            cache: false,
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
            processData: false
        });
```

server side code:

```
var file = req.file('upload');
    //var extension = file.fd.slice((file.fd.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
    //var newName = uuid.v4();
    //file.fd = newName + extension;

    file.upload({
            // don't allow the total upload size to exceed ~4MB
            maxBytes: 5000000,
            adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
            key: sails.config.auth.aws.key,
            secret: sails.config.auth.aws.secret,
            bucket: 'bucketName'
        }, function whenDone(error, uploadedFiles) {

 ...
```

I have two problems:

1) There seem to be no files going through. I am not sure where I am losing the file because dataURLtoBlob is definitely producing a blob...

2) How can I manipulate the file name prior to sending the file to amazon (You can see what I was attempting to do in the commented out lines)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

> HTML code

```
<form name='form1' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id='form-id'>
    <input type='submit' id='addtag' value='Add' />
</form>
```

> jQuery code

```
$("#form-id").on('submit',(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "file-to-call.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: new FormData(this),
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //handle success
        }
   });
}));
```